# Xcode 11 vertical position of editors

Tags: xcode, xcode11

In Xcode 10 (and earlier) we could have two editors vertically stacked on top of each other. I have not managed to do that in Xcode 11, only horizontally stacked, which is not optimal using my rotated monitor (using my monitor "in portrait" mode).

Is it possible to vertically align editors?

Answer (score 2):

Choosing File > New > Editor Below will add an editor below the current editor and tell Xcode to vertically stack future editors for that project. You can also choose View > Change Editor Orientation to toggle stacking editors vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mark's answer I knew that it was possible to do vertical alignment of editors, but just now I also discovered that the good old shortcut gets updated according to current Editor aligment.

`CMD + SHIFT + O` ('Open quickly')
Enter name of type/file you would like to open in a new editor, select the file in the list
Followed by

### `ALT + ENTER` to open the selected file in a new editor (using latest preferred alignemt)